# batch code to get todays day and compare strings

Tags: batch-file

I have this code to get the todays date... but when I try to compare strings it fails and doesn't give me the correct result.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion


    @For /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=. " %%A in ('Date /t') do @( 
        Set Day=%%A
        Set Month=%%B
        Set Year=%%C
    )

    @echo DAY = %Day%

    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 5

    IF "%Day%" == "tue"( @echo "YES"  %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 5 )



%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 5
```

How can I compare it to todays date and get the ECHO if it matches?

Comment: you need space here `IF /i "%Day%" == "tue"(`   -> `IF /i "%Day%" == "tue" (`

Comment: Your `if` statement is case-sensitive right now, so it's comparing `Tue` to `tue`, which will return false. You need the `/I` flag.

Comment: Works. Can you post the WHOLE code bellow so I can give it best answer tag and pints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things are going on here. First, you need a space between `"tue"` and `(` so that batch interprets the `if` statement correctly.

Secondly, the day of the week is returned by `date /t` with an initial capital letter, in this case, it will return the string `Tue`. However, `if` statements by default are case-sensitive, and you're checking against a value of `tue`, which is *not* equal to `Tue`. Fortunately, `if` has an `/I` option that tells `if` to do a case-insensitive comparison.

Finally, you need a newline between `@echo yes` and the `timeout` command, otherwise the timeout gets echoed instead of performed.

The entire check would look like this:

```
IF /i "%Day%" == "tue" (
    @echo "YES"
    %SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe 5
)
```